# Snake movement in C using tiles and sprites

Tags: c

I`m creating snake movement using tiles. I have a grid of 32 by 32 tiles with each tile being selected the following function:

```
tile[y][x]=sprite;
```

So far I have been using the following function to move the snake up and down:

```
void up(int Snake_Length){
    dir=0;
    tile[ydir--][xdir]=snake;   
}
void down(int Snake_Length){
    dir=1;
    tile[ydir++][xdir]=snake;   
}

void left(int Snake_Length){
    dir=2;
    tile[ydir][xdir--]=snake;
}

void right(int Snake_Length){
    dir=3;
    tile[ydir][xdir++]=snake;
}
```

The problem is this function only works when my snake is a single tile. When the number of tiles increases as the snake size increases, I`m having trouble changing the direction of the snake.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use global variables.  Do consider using loops.  You'll need to have a trace of where the snake has been so you can move the lead tile (its head) forward one space in the appropriate direction (and maybe change what was the head to a body tile), and then delete the last tile (its tail), replacing it with a background image (and maybe change what was a body tile to the tail tile).  You'll also need to check that the new square isn't one that is already occupied by part of the snake; usually, that either isn't allowed or leads to 'end of game' (in defeat).

Comment: not a good question, but you can do this by doing a "follow the leader" approach

Comment: When moving left or right in a straight i am able to keep track of the position of the last tile but when i move up or down i lose track of it. What is the best way to calculate the position of the last tile given x any y coordinates of the head and snake length .